# Scroll to element on page load in Chrome

Tags: jquery, hash, scroll, pageload

Is it possible to scroll to an element with id taken from url hash on page load in Chrome? I've googled and tried everything, but nothing seems to work in Chrome. For example, the following code works in Safari, but does nothing in Chrome:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  if(location.hash) {
    var target = location.hash;
    location.hash = '';
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top + 'px'}, 300);
  }
});
```

Comment: Try `$(window)` instead of `$('html,body')`

Comment: Chrome responds to `$(document).ready(function () {})`...

Comment: Tried both $(window) instead of $('html,body') and $(document).ready(function () {}). Neither works in Chrome and even breaks Safari.

Comment: Remove the `+ 'px'`. scrollTop expects a number.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in Chrome is, that `DOMContentLoaded` gets fired when `document.readyState` is `interactive`, at that point in time it isn't possible to scroll programatically yet though. While a timeout MIGHT work, depending on how long it is and how fast the page loads, this is the foolproof solution:

```
  let callback = () => {
        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
              $(selector).animate({
                    scrollTop: value
              }, time);
        }
  };

  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        callback();
  } else {
        document.addEventListener('readystatechange', callback);
  }
```

In this snippet, the `readyState` is checked right away, if it is already `complete`, the callback gets called immediately, if not, we add an eventlistener to the `readystatechange` event and call the callback once the `readyState` is `complete`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to use `window.location.hash` instead of just `location.hash`. And here is the working snippet, I have tested it in Chrome (the example is without `window.location.hash`, just scrolling):

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#elementToScroll").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.regular {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 5px black solid;
  margin: 16px;
}

#elementToScroll {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 5px black solid;
  margin: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="regular"></div>
<div class="regular"></div>
<div class="regular"></div>
<div id="elementToScroll"></div>
```

Here:

```
$(selector).animate({
    scrollTop: value
}, time);
```

we are animating `scrollTop` method, and here:

```
$(element).offset().top
```

we are getting element's offset from top of the page.

Comment: This is basically the same as my example and it does not work on Chrome for Mac (Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Comment: @iamfredrik, and the snippet doesn't work too? Or only in your project?

Comment: The snippet works, but it doesn't answer the question, because you are defining the #elementToScroll in the snippet. The #elementToScroll needs to be loaded from location.hash and then it no longer works.

Comment: @iamfredrik, I gave you the basic understanding of the issue, sure, you need to adapt it to your needs

Comment: I don't understand how your example differs from the one I provided initially. It does exactly the same thing when defining a target element in the script. The problem is that it doesn't work when the target element is taken from the url, using var target = location.hash;

Comment: @iamfredrik, if the issue is in getting location hash, it should be `window.location.hash`, not just `location.hash`

Comment: Either way should work https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

Comment: It seems like chrome is too fast. It tries to scroll to the element before the page has fully loaded and hence it ends up at the top. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: @iamfredrik, if it really tries to scroll to the element before the page has fully loaded, so an empty timeout should solve the issue. `setTimeout(function() { if(location.hash) {...} })`. Or try to use `$(document).ready(function() {...})` instead of `$(window).load(function() {...})`, it will start the execution only when the document will be ready. First try `$(document).ready` way, or if it will not work, try to use `setTimeout` or both of them, but I think `$(document).ready` will work.

Comment: Yes, I posted about the setTimeout solution yesterday. I tried $(document).ready before and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this one :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").scroll(function(){
       location.hash = "part5";
       alert(location.hash)
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Try the scrollbar in the div</p>

<div style="border:1px solid black;width:200px;height:100px;overflow:scroll;">In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
<br><br>
'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
</div>

<p>Scrolled <span>0</span> times.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, I don't know how to implement it in plain javascript. Can you provide a working example?

Comment: i just updated my anwer in JQuery so you can play with the codes and get what you need :)

Comment: I don't see how this example would solve the problem. The .scroll() function does not scroll, but reacts on user scroll. I'm looking for a solution that uses .scrollTop() to automatically scroll the page to the hash provided by the url.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome attempts to scroll before the page has loaded, so I solved the problem with a timeout function inside the window load function. Not sure if it's the best solution, but it works.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $("html, body").animate({
     scrollTop: $(target).offset().top}, 300);
}, 1000);
```